# How to display XML radio information in plain text on Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox, internet-radio, xml, aac

My local radio station provide an XML feed on the AAC file. Here is the url :

http://ckmf-aac.akacast.akamaistream.net/7/493/102120/v1/astral.akacast.akamaistream.net/ckmf-aac

At each song, there is a new popup indicating wich song is playing, but it is displayed as XML, and non text. I wonder if there is any plugins, or software, for displaying content of XML, and non XML.

Screenshot :
[image: Rythmbox screenshot]

Thanks!

Comment: doubtful there is a plugin.  However you should file a bug-report since this is the sort of thing that should actually be in the core product: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=rhythmbox

Comment: @fossfreedom Posted in [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=762118)  Thanks!

Comment: excellent - had a quick look - hopefully the maintainers will look at this soon.